# How to run server for API testing with JEST?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

Im really new to Unit tests.

I have a nodeJS server written in HapiJS. I do have a server.ts file to initialize the server and get it running. The APIs work just fine using POSTMAN. I have to test this using JEST and i was told to not run the backend server from a different console, but rather let Jest do it. How do i initialize the server?